# how to get all values of input number field which is generated in *ngfor

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

i have a table displaying cart products, in quantity field, i have a option for user to increase or decrease quantity,if i have update btn inside for loop, it is giving seperate btns for each, but i need single update btn outside for loop that gets all values of input field..

```
 <tbody  *ngFor="let cartproducts of  cartpro.cartproducts ">

     <input id="number"   type="number" value="{{cartproducts.quantity}}" (change)="callMethod($event)"   class="updatequan"> </tbody>
```

updatebtn:

```
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-success"  (click)="updatecart($event)">Update cart </button>
```

component.ts

```
    callMethod(e:any)
      {
    
    this.quantity=  e.target.value
    console.log("current quantity",this.quantity)
    
    }

 
  updatecart(e:any){
    console.log("udpate to",this.quantity)
  }
```

if updatebtn is outside forloop, it is working , but it is showing the recently changed...but i need all changed stored in []

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at `ReactiveFormsModule`

Basically you define a form and using `.value` property you can get any property you need

In your component file

```typescript
  constructor(private fb: FormBbuilder) { }
   cartpro = this.fb.group({
    cartProducts this.fb.array([
    ])
  })
  get cartProducts() {
    return this.cartpro.get('cartProducts ') as FormArray
  }
```

and in your html

```
<form [formGroup]='cartpro'>
  <tbody formArrayName='cartProducts'>
    <tr *ngFor="let cartproduct of cartProducts" [formGroupName]='i'>
      <input id="number" type="number" formControlName='quantity' class="updatequan"> 
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</form>
```

Basically you now you can access the value of products with `this.cartProducts.value`

Comment: i'll try and get back to u :)